# Use hard coded dates to filter report

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to work out how to filter reports using start and end dates in a "Rounds" data source (Google Sheet). It includes the following fields for each round:

- Round Name
- Start Date
- End Date

I want to use the Start Date and End Date from the "Rounds" data source to filter a Google Analytics data source between these two dates.

Honestly, I don't know where to start. Do I need to blend the data and then apply a custom filter? Create a custom dimension and use some logic like "BETWEEN" etc? Create a custom parameter and hardcode the dates?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.